# Augmented reality in android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I have just started developing an application on android based on augmented reality, I just want to know is there any plugins or development kit required for augmented reality also I have gone through some of the development kit as follows,

1. ARToolKit
2. FLARToolKit and FLARManager for Adobe Flash
3. SLARToolkit
4. AR-media™ Plugin for Google™ SketchUp™
5. NyARToolkit
6. LinceoVR
7. HandyAR
8. Total Immersion – D’Fusion Studio
9. Unifeye Mobile

and I want to know, which would be the better... My application is based on text translator and face recognition. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To do face recognition  try to use OpenCV. It have got in built library functions which can make life easier. Refer below links.

[OpenCV -Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)

[OpenCV - Java](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Augmented reality (AR) is a term for a live direct or indirect view of a physical, real-world environment whose elements are augmented by virtual computer-generated sensory input, such as sound or graphics. It is related to a more general concept called mediated reality, in which a view of reality is modified (possibly even diminished rather than augmented) by a computer. As a result, the technology functions by enhancing one’s current perception of reality.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android_augmented-reality/